# No. of control and state variables in optimal control theory

Tags: optimal-control

I am given a question in which I can identify 2 control variables and 1 state variable. Can I check if I can still apply Hamiltonian here to solve this question? I have only dealt with questions where the number of control variables is the same as the number of state variables, and am thus unsure.